# how can i download this source code from google api java client

Tags: google-api

I want this [sample project](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2Fcalendar-android-sample) but I can't find how to download it, any idea how is it possible?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Mercurial. Then run this command as specified in the [Checkout page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/checkout?repo=samples) -

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/
```